# Screen becoming unresponsive after dismissing popup

Tags: android, alert

I am having a class which is for showing an alert popup. I am launching that alert from a class in the same package. Also I am dismissing that popup when i receive an event from the same class.
Now when i am dismissing the popup when i receive the event the popup is being dismissed, but screen  is becoming unresponsive. Then we need to press back button or home key to come out of that.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please paste your code at which you show your popup.

Comment: alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
              
     @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismisspopup();
        finish();
                }
        });
        dlg = alert.show();
        isVisible = true;
        MonitorPopup runnable = new MonitorPopup();
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        
        t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            t.cancel(); 
            dismisspopup();
   finish();
        }
        }, 30000);
 }

Answer (score 1):

I thing screen become unresponsive due to the activity showing popup not close  after  popup is being dismissed. so you should call activity  finish(); method to finish the activity.